# SQL: How to insert data in specific column with specific id as well

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, codeigniter-3

Is it possible to perform kind of that query on single table?

I have read that it could be done by multiple tables (inserting in first table by selecting that specific value from second )

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is it possible to perform kind of that query on single table?*

Yes, it is possible:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                       CustomerName VARCHAR(100), Country VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
VALUES ('John', 'USA'), ('Martin','Germany');

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT CustomerName, Country 
FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Germany';

SELECT *
FROM Customers;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/NHK31540)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that `Table Spool` is required to avoid [`Halloween Effect`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2008/02/27/halloween-protection/)

[image]

Comment: the **live demo** is not working, and there they say " Any existing rows in the target table are unaffected " hoping we can update our table row